# Как создать функционал EditText и TextView в одном поле?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-textview

Требуется следующее - пользователь видит строчку "Введите Вашу цель" нажимает на данную строчку, добавляет текст и по нажатию на кнопку "ок" на клавиатуре, введенный текст должен быть сохранен и показан при всех следующих открытиях приложения, как это реализовать?

Comment: Никакого совмещения с `TextView` не требуется, `EditText` - наследник `TextView` и так (реализует все методы и параметры `TextView`). У `EditText` есть [параметр `android:hint`](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/edittext.php#hint), который выводит подсказку ввода. Как сохранить ввод есть множество вариантов и из вашего вопроса нельзя выбрать правильный, так как никаких подробностей реализации вы не написали, но возможно вам поможет сохранение в `SharedPreferences` с использованием колбэков `onSaveInstanceState()` и `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

Comment: Для отображения подсказки в EditText используйте свойство ```android:hint```. При вводе значений в поле подсказка исчезнет. Если удалить все значения из поля, то снова появится. Про последующие открытия приложения с сохраненными данными стоит посмотреть в сторону ```Preferences```.